# there is no package called ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ on Clean Install

Tags: r, bioconductor

Clean install with R 4.0 on Sierra and started re-installing packages. I need to use DESeq2 and have the error

```r
> In install.packages(...) :
>  installation of package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I compile I have this error:

```r
> Loading required package: GenomicRanges Loading required package:
> GenomeInfoDb Error: package or namespace load failed for
> ‘GenomeInfoDb’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  there is no package called
> ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ Error: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ could not be loaded
```

I installed bioconductor with:

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.11")
```

And DESeq2 via the BiocManager: I've tried `BiocManager::install("DESeq2")` and `BiocManager::install(c("GenomeInfoDb","GenoneInfoDbData")`

When I install, it prints that 'dbplyr', 'foreign', 'haven', 'httpuv', 'nlme', 'rtracklayer' are old packages and no matter how  I try to update them, it reads the same warning.

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 2):

I went back to R 3.6.1 for now and it worked fine